# Hide url parameters in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string

I am using this:

```
document.location ='my different asp.net page?=myparams'
```

Is there a way to hide the values of the params in the URL displayed on the browser?

I know I could use hidden Form values and I know I can encrypt the values (which is what I will do if no joy here).

Is there a simpler tidier way of doing this? Perhaps via JQuery.

Comment: To what end? You're telling the user to request something, why does it matter that they can see what is being requested?

Comment: You can set the parameters from JS (`location.search = params`), but that'll show the parameter in the url bar. As far as I know, there's not really a way to "post" parameters.

Comment: If you do not want to pass the values in the querystring, than you can not use a GET request.

Comment: Doing this with JS sounds messy. Please look at method 1 here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Comment: @Quentin  Hi, thanks for your comment. I actually agree with you. It should not be an issue.  I normally use session objects but the very fact the session_end is not guarantee to trigger I need to find another mechanism to use.  By passing the values via query string I can afford using the session object. My quest to hide a querystring is just habit an interest to know if this is possible

Comment: @closers why?  was the question so bad or are their people who have an agenda?

Comment: There is no way to HIDE a querystring. You either have the values or you do not. If you do not want it, you have to make POST requests to pass the information from page to page.

Comment: @epascarello OK.  BTW are you 1 of the donw-voters?

Comment: @closers - yawn! Get a life! :)

Comment: @closers notice it is always people with high profile scores that have an arrogant attitude that vote down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just trying to hide the url parameters from the address bar in the browser then you could use an [iframe](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/iframe).

Comment: Here's a [sample](http://www.dev-explorer.com/articles/full-page-iframe) of a full page iFrame.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to set document.location to a second page, that page keep param values in a session variable and redirect to your desired one.

document.location = "redirectpage.php?param=value"

In redirectpage.php

$_SESSION['param']=$_GET['param];
header('Location: ' . desired_page?param=value);

By this way, value of param will be only displayed in a very short time when redirectpage.php redirecting to desired page.

Hope it helps

Btw, can you explain how hidden Form works in this case?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. I have never implemented hidden forms. I have heard that is a possible solution.  thanks so much for your time :)