# How to call another dashboard in Pentaho using POST method

Tags: javascript, url, post, business-intelligence, pentaho-cde

I am using **Open Source Pentaho CDE** as BI tool for my project. In my Dashboard im using some yearly data to represent charts. And i need Drill Down functionality to know the data of the particular year in another dashboard.

If i click the year 2008 in the bar chart means i have to generate another dashboard contains information regarding that year itself.

```
function sendParameter(scene){
       var url="http://localhost:8080/pentaho/api/repos/%3Ahome%3Atiffany%3ADashboardWithAdventuresDBDrilDown2.wcdf/generatedContent";

       var vars = scene.vars;
       var c = vars.category.value;
       var v = vars.value.value;

       window.location=url+"?param_custom_state="+c;
}
```

URL in the Browser is like :

```
http://localhost:8080/pentaho/api/repos/%3Ahome%3Atiffany%3ADashboardWithAdventuresDBDrilDown2.wcdf/generatedContent?param_custom_state=2007
```

I have used this script to call another dashboard from current dashboard. But **it is in the form of Get method. I dont want to show the parameters in the URL**.

How can i achieve it. Is there any other way to **get Drill Down using Javascript in Pentaho CDE**.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only need to hide the parameters of url, you can either use an iframe or ajax request instead of directly calling the url location.

Similar question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580647/hide-url-parameters-in-javascript)

Hope it helps :)